# How to recover chrome bookmarks from browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I recently deleted bookmark folder and cant recover it from bookmarks.bak file in user profile. Bookmark backup file was already overwritten. However I noticed that there is a star nex to items in browsing history. Is there some way to recreate bookmarks from browsing history?